# Altium Component Part Description

Tags: components, altium, library

A Component in the Library has 11 Parts. 
At the moment I get a Description for Component as a whole. Is there a way to change Description of each Part?

- What I have: a component have only one description, Descriptions of parts are empty.
- What I need: next to each Part of the component to have a description like "Power", "Grounds", "Signals".

Look at the Picture and try to guess what each separate Part of the Component does.

[image: Sch Library with empty Parts Descriptions]

Comment: Excellent question, let me look into this. Off the top of my head, though, I don't think so. Would be a great feature request

Comment: This question could save lives... and unnecessary overtime.

Comment: Yep, doesn't look like that option exists at the moment. I suggest posting to the feature request page: https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Ideas/New . This feature would be extremely useful to me as I am currently working on a design with an FPGA and I have no idea what the difference between U1A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H is without opening each part.

Comment: There's a bit of history embedded in this feature (or lack of).  Multi part components were really just things like logic gates or multi-up opamps, where the sub parts were all, most-commonly, identical.  CPLD's, FPGA's , and uC's could benefit from your idea.  Good luck.

Comment: I've added a Feature Request:
https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Idea/8962
Thank's for your tips!

Comment: If you like the possibility to change names of different Component Parts, vote for it:
https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Idea/9000

Comment: At the time this Idea has only 6 Votes. Please add your Vote if you like it. Update.
https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Idea/9000

Answer (score 1):

Yep, doesn't look like that option exists at the moment. I suggest posting to the feature request page: bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Ideas/New . This feature would be extremely useful to me as I am currently working on a design with an FPGA and I have no idea what the difference between U1A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H is without opening each part. – DerStrom8 Feb 6 at 17:35

Comment: If I'd known this should have been posted as an answer instead of a comment I would have posted it myself =P

Comment: @DerStrom8 The answer is posted as community wiki and attributed to you. I have been going through some of the old unanswered questions with a view to cleaning them up. There is a tendency for questions with good answers in the comments to be subsequently ignored. If you know of any other questions where you have done this you might want to consider converting your comments to answers.